# Capybara::ElementNotFound Exception when the element is constructed dynamically

Tags: ruby, capybara, site-prism

In cases when we have a dynamic content population in a span tag,
for e.g.,

```
  .detail
    %label Sku:
    %span.#sku.detail= @deal.sku
```

When the deal in the above example doesn't have sku associated, the span element in the html will be as below 
without any content in it.

```
 <div class="detail">
<label>Sku:</label>
<span id="sku" class="detail"></span>
 </div>
```

If the SitePrism element is defined to look for this for e.g.,

```
element :sku, "#sku"
```

and if "@sample_page" is reference to my Site Prism page, and I refer sku as

```
@sample_page.sku.text
```

we will get Capybara::ElementNotFound Exception

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this we can check as below

```
@sample_page.has_sku?
```

and if the element is available then proceed with the actions as required.

This will omit Capybara::ElementNotFound Exception

Answer (score 0):

When the span has no content it is not visible and thus not found.  If you still want to find it, change your element to something like:

```
element :sku, "#sku", visible: false
```